# Multiple tables with node mysql-model?

Tags: mysql, node.js, model

I'm working on a project where I use mysql-model and I don't really understand how models work when we have multiple tables.

I have some code on my model user.js:

```
var mysqlcon = require('../models/db_connexion');

var User_model = mysqlcon.extend({
  tableName: "users"
});

var log_user = new User_model();
```

Some code ...

Then a function to find the user's role:

```
module.exports.findUserRole = function(userId,callback){
  let findUserRoleId = "SELECT role_id FROM users WHERE id = "+userId;

  log_user.query(findUserRoleId,function(err,rows,fields){
    let role_id = rows[0].role_id;
    let findRolesInfo = "SELECT role_name,role_power FROM roles WHERE role_id = " + role_id;
    log_user.query(findRolesInfo,callback)
  })
```

And when I call this function, it returns me what I want, but I don't understand why.

My User_model isn't normally using only the table "users" ? So why can I also access to the table "roles" ?

I've searched on the [npm documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql-model) and googled it, but didn't found anything, or I missed it.

Thanks for your explanation.

And sorry if I missed something with the presentation, that's my first post.